# Download CSV not working in customBodyRender columns in mui datatables

Tags: download, export-to-csv, mui-datatable

I am trying to download CSV from **mui datatables** when I try to download it will get **[Object]** notation instead of values of payer object. 
this issue comes only when rendering objects. Strings are fine at all.

[image]

#### is there a way to customize the download action?

#### do I need to get support from the outside library?

this is my code

```
const columns = [
  {
    name: "payer",
    label: <p style={styles.colHeader}>{"Payer"}</p>,
    options: {
      customBodyRender: (payer) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography
              style={styles.firstLine}
            >{`${payer.firstName} ${payer.lastName}`}</Typography>
            <Typography style={styles.secondLine}>
              {`Membership ID : ${payer.membership}`}
            </Typography>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      },
    },
  },
]

const options = {
  filterType: "checkbox",
};


const data = [
  {
    payer: {
      firstName: "SUNIL",
      lastName: "WAIDYARATHNE",
      membership: "3302",
    },
  },
  {
    payer: {
      firstName: "DANAPALA",
      lastName: "GUNASIRI",
      membership: "3302",
    },
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

download action can override in **OnDownload** Options

1. why this happens
2. how to solve this

in your column -> column Name is ***player***, mui-datatables map column `name` in the `columns` object `property` of the `data` object. there is object for player instead of string. that's how it prints *[Object object]*

to override that function use OnDownload option in the mui-datatables.

```
const options = {
  filterType: "checkbox",
  onDownload: (buildHead, buildBody, columns, data) => {
    buildHead = () => {
       return ["col-1","col-2"]
    }
    buildBody = () => {
     return [["A", "B"],["C", "D"]];
    }
    return "\uFEFF" + buildHead() + buildBody();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a particular column to include in download(csv) or not by 'download' key in options of that column. Which is by default true. You have to make it false as shown below.

```js
const columns = [
  {
    name: "payer",
    label: <p style={styles.colHeader}>{"Payer"}</p>,
    options: {
      download: false, //just add this
      customBodyRender: (payer) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography
              style={styles.firstLine}
            >{`${payer.firstName} ${payer.lastName}`}</Typography>
            <Typography style={styles.secondLine}>
              {`Membership ID : ${payer.membership}`}
            </Typography>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      },
    },
  },
]
```